How to use Xdebug for php in mediawiki
I am having trouble setting up xdebug in my local mediawiki environemtn. As per docs it should have been ready to use but I can not step through anything nor will it catch any break points. I am using vs code as my IDE. Ive tried just about everything that ive found on both mediawiki, chatgpt, xdebug.com and etc.
.env file
MW_SCRIPT_PATH=/w
MW_SERVER=http://localhost:8080
MW_DOCKER_PORT=8080
MEDIAWIKI_USER=[removed for privacy]
MEDIAWIKI_PASSWORD=[removed for privacy]
XDEBUG_CONFIG='mode=debug start_with_request=trigger client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9003 idekey=VSCODE' 
XDEBUG_MODE=debug
XDEBUG_ENABLE=true
XHPROF_ENABLE=true


launch.jason
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/w": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}

